# Puppet: Could not request certificate

Tags: puppet

When I start puppet agent I get this error

```
Could not request certificate: Could not intern from text/plain: Certname "puppet ca: localhost/localdomain" must not contain unprintable or non-ASCII characters
```

Both puppet master and agent versions are 3.8.7

In both master and agent `/etc/hosts` file I added these lines:

```
10.11.22.166 pclient
10.11.22.173 pmaster
```

I can ping both pclient and pmaster from each other.

In puppet master puppet.conf I added this line:

```
[master]
certname = pmaster
```

In puppet agent puppet.conf file I added this line in [main] block:

```
server = pmaster
```

Enabled 8140 port:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT
```

Puppet Master log:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 4 (0x4)
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: CN=Puppet CA: localhost/localdomain
    Validity
        Not Before: May  3 13:29:42 2016 GMT
        Not After : May  3 13:29:42 2021 GMT
    Subject: CN=pmaster
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (4096 bit)
```

Comment: can you try
`export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`
and then start the command again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of

> Puppet CA: localhost/localdomain

There is a / in it which is a non-ASCII characters but my problem is different i already assign the different host name so delete the ssl dir which is in /var/lib/puppet/ssl and than resign it again using this command

```
# puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize
```